# UML, Diagrama de casos de uso

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml, casos-de-uso

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao diagrama de casos de uso, segue a versão original que eu montei:

[image: Diagrama original]

Porém, ao escrever a descrição dos casos de uso, tive uma ideia que pode representar melhor a necessidade do sistema.

O núcleo pedagógico cadastra estágio mas para cadastrar o estágio é necessário informações da empresa em que o estagiando está, logo cadastrar empresa é um extend de cadastra estágio que mesmo assim está linkado ao ator núcleo pedagógico?

Existe também o caso de uso de designar professor, que, após o cadastramento pela parte do núcleo pedagógico, o coordenador de estágio designa um professor para ser um orientador do estagiando, seria então Designar professor um include de cadastrar estágio, também linkado com coordenador de estágio que é quem tem acesso?

Criei um diagrama exemplo que melhor explica minha duvida:[image: Exemplo de diagrama]

Resumindo minha dúvida: existe as ligações de extend e include ou estou entendendo o conceito errado?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É importante reforçar os conceitos de ***include e extend***. Talvez apenas isso faça com que você mesmo resolva sua dúvida. Então vamos lá...

- ### include:

  Quando usamos o **include**, estamos indicando que **sempre** que o caso de uso A for executado, o caso de uso B será executado. Pode-se então simplificar dizendo que A inclui B.
- ### extend:

  Já quando usamos o **extend**, o caso de uso não será necessariamente executado todas as vezes. Ou seja, o caso de uso **poderá ou não** ser executado também. É importante lembrar que a *ponta da seta* estará para o lado que recebe a funcionalidade estendida.

[image: Exemplo gráfico]

Agora vamos ao seu problema:

O ator núcleo pedagógico, cadastra o estágio e não irá **necessariamente** cadastrar a empresa. Pelo simples motivo de existir a possibilidade que ela já tenha sido cadastrada antes. Logo, você usou corretamente o **extend**. Porém, ele **não** estará ligado diretamente ao ator.

Atenção na direção das setas no include! Como escreveu, dá a entender que quando o ator designar o professor ele terá que cadastrar o estágio (A inclui B, lembra?).

[image: Exemplo Gráfico]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, iluminou muito meu conceito em diagramas de caso de uso! A seta include de Designar professor e cadastrar estágio fiz na desatenção mesmo, mas as outras eu realmente estava com o conceito errado.